# Flex child wrapping when it shouldn't; flex-wrap: nowrap not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

No idea why, but `flex-flow: row nowrap` doesn't seem to be preventing the orange div from wrapping. The green and orange divs should be side by side - what am I doing wrong here? The orange div also seems to have no height.

Any help would be appreciated here, thank you.

```css
.appShopSummaryContainer {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.appShopSummaryProductWrap {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  display: flex;
}
.appShopSummaryImg {
 flex-basis: 40%; /* flex: 0 0 40% */
  width: 40%;
 height: auto;
 padding-bottom: 26.667%;
  background: green;
}
.appShopSummaryInfo {
  flex-basis: 60%; /* flex: 0 0 60% */
  width: 60%;
  background: orange;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='appShopSummaryContainer'>
  <div class='appShopSummaryProductWrap'>
    <a href='#'><div class='appShopSummaryImg'></div>erg</a>
    <div class='appShopSummaryInfo'>wgh</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='appShopSummaryProductWrap'>
    <a href='#'><div class='appShopSummaryImg'></div>jyu</a>
    <div class='appShopSummaryInfo'>erge</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a screenshot with desired result as a wireframe, it is hard to understand what you want exactly.

Comment: Missing .appShopSummaryProductWrap {display: flex} for start, i.e. their parent needs to be displayed as flex.

Comment: I've added that but doesnt seem to do the trick. I've edited the fiddle to include some random text inside the divs, otherwise there's no height. Essentially there should be none of the dummy text inside the divs, and the width of the green div should be 40% and 60% for orange div. And the height of green div should be 26.6% of its width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try out this code

```
<div class="appShopSummaryContainer">
  <div class="appShopSummaryProductWrap">
   <a href=""class="appShopSummaryImg"></a>
    <div class="appShopSummaryInfo"></div>
</div>
</div>
</br>
<div class='appShopSummaryContainer'>
  <div class='appShopSummaryProductWrap'>
    <a href='#'class='appShopSummaryImg' ><div>test</div></a>
    <div class='appShopSummaryInfo'>test1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css goes here

```
.appShopSummaryContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.appShopSummaryProductWrap {
 flex-basis: 100%;
  background: pink;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.appShopSummaryImg {
  flex-basis: 40%; /* flex: 0 0 40% */
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 26.667%;
  background: green;
}

.appShopSummaryInfo {
  flex-basis: 60%; /* flex: 0 0 60% */
  width: 60%;
  background: orange;
    padding-bottom: 26.667%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you - didn't think to make it like that with the a tag. Much appreciated